# Document similarity using LSA in R

Tags: r, lsa

I am working on LSA (using R) for Document Similarity Analysis.
Here are my steps

1. Imported the text data & created Corpus. Did basis Corpus operations like stemming, white space removal etc
2. Created LSA space as below

   `tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(chat_corpus)
   tdm_matrix <- as.matrix(tdm) 
   tdm.lsa <- lw_bintf(tdm_matrix)*gw_idf(tdm_matrix)
   lsaSpace <- lsa(tdm.lsa)`
3. Multi Dimensional Modelling (MDS) on LSA

'

```
dist.mat.lsa <- dist(t(as.textmatrix(lsaSpace)))
fit <- cmdscale(dist.mat.lsa,eig = T)
points <- data.frame(fit1$points,row.names=chat$text)
```

I want to create a matrix/data frame showing how similar the texts are (as shown in the attachment Result).  Rows & Columns will be the texts to match while the cell values will be their similarity value. Ideally the diagonal values will be one 1 (perfect match) while the rest of the cell values will be lesser than 1.

Please trow some insights into how to do this. Thanks in advance

Note : I got the python code for this but need the same in R

```
similarity = np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
pd.DataFrame(similarity,index=example, columns=example).head(10)
```

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpfMK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you first need to take the `S_k` and `D_k` matrices from the lsa space you've created and multiply `S_k` by the transpose of `D_k`  to get a `k` by `n` matrix, where `k` is the number of dimensions and `n` is the number of documents. This code would be as follows:

`lsaMatrix <- diag(myLSAspace$sk) %*% t(myLSAspace$dk)`

Then it's as simple as putting the resulting matrix through the `cosine` function from the `lsa` package:

`simMatrix <- cosine(lsaMatrix)`

Which will result in an `n^2` size similarity matrix which can then be used for clustering etc.

You can read more about the `S_k` and `D_k` matrices in the `lsa` package documentation, they're outputs of the SVD applied.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsa/lsa.pdf